# Rays starting in an octree node

Tags: octree

I just fixed a bug where rays *starting and ending* in an octree node were not detected as octree node hits (because the ray doesn't hit the sides).

I'm changing the code to check *if a ray starts in the octree node, then it is an automatic node hit*.

Any reason to *not* do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your ray starts in an octree node, then it could, of course, hit something in that node.  If you ignored the node in which the ray starts, you risk missing the closest hit.

So, no, there is no reason *not* to do it because you *should* do it.

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly the way to do it, provided that's a leaf node. If not, you need to drill down to subsequent levels to raymarch there.